# Use of Progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have created an app where i have 5 buttons for streaming 5 different live channels. Along with 5 buttons i have a progressbar(ring). Iam using progress bar since the videos are taking time to load. I have written the main code in onBackground() of AsyncTask which returns some value which is called in the click event of the button. Since all 5 buttons have different url assigned, how can i use the same onBackground() for all 5 buttons? What to do in this case?Can anyone please provide me with a good example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onBackground()` is part of AsyncTask. It got nothing common with buttons or other UI elements. If you want to reuse the code simply pass your UI as argument to AsyncTask constructor and then use it when needed.

Comment: I know that onBackground() is part of AsyncTask, but how can I pass UI as argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
Video Path
```

**private static String file_url = "url";**

```
  in your activity
```

**new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);**

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

Background Async Task to download file



/**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
                // progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/demo.mp4");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded video into video view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            String videopath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/demo.mp4";
            // setting downloaded into image view

        }

    }
```